# Inner Join & Count, Microsoft SQL

Tags: count, nested, inner-join

I am  trying to do a count inside a nested statement with inner join

```
select  a.app_id, a.first_name, a.last_name, d.svd_id
from    wwhs_app a inner join
        wwhs_svc d on a.app_id = d.app_id
where   a.app_id in(
        select  top 50 app_id
        from wwhs_app
        Where app_create_dt > '2012-07-23 00:00:00')
```

I need a count of svd_id as well, but I keep getting errors every way I try. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to count for svd_id but it's not in the query.
Did you mean 'app_id'?
Try this...

```
    SELECT a.app_id, a.first_name, a.last_name, d.svd_id
    FROM wwhs_app a
    INNER JOIN wwhs_svc d on a.app_id = d.app_id
    WHERE a.app_id in (
         SELECT TOP 50 app_id, COUNT(*) as id_count
         FROM wwhs_app
         WHERE app_create_dt > '2012-07-23 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY app_id ORDER BY id_count)
```